# How to inject caching into Zend_Db

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching

I'm looking at ways to reduce the number of queries that are being performed on my MySQL server.

The application and database servers are on separate machines, so it seems caching previous query results on the application server is not a bad option to pursue. Obviously there are other strategies like reducing the number of queries and optimizing the query statements, however I don't think I should discount query caching as an option.

I was initially thinking that I could easily turn on some form of query caching in the `Zend_Db` object, however the closest I've come to seeing something crosscut is the `Zend_Db_Profiler`.

One approach I was considering was to create a proxy for my `Zend_Db_Adapter` object. Something to the effect of:

```
/**
 * Initialize the database.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function _initDb() {
    // Instantiate a connection to the database
    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
    $db = new MyProject_Db_Proxy (
                Zend_Db::factory($config->resources->db->adapter, 
                                 $config->resources->db->params)
              );

    // Store the database object in the registry
    Zend_Registry::set('db', $db);

    Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter('db');
}
```

I've looked through the various `Zend_Db` interfaces and classes and it looks possible that I could inject caching into the `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::query()` method via the proxy. Something to the effect of:

```
public MyProject_Db_Proxy() {

  private $_adapter = null;
  ...
  public function query($sql, $bind = array()) {
    // Generate the cache key by joining and hashing $sql and $bind
    // Check to see if key is in cache, return if found
    // Execute query
    $stmt = this->_adapter->query($sql, $bind);
    // Cache result
  }
  ...
}
```

My question is: **Is there a better/easier way to inject caching into Zend_Db?**

Comment: Enable your databases query cache.

Comment: Note that I'm using Zend Framework 1.11.11 with the PDO MySQL adapter.

Comment: @hakre Are you suggesting that the database query cache will get rid of the network round trip? Can you point me to resources for this?

Comment: No it won't for the network roundtrip. If you want to prevent the network roundtrip, you need client side query caching, see http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQLnd_Query_Cache_Plugin_for_PHP

Comment: @hakre I'll keep that plugin in mind. It's fairly new and may require a database upgrade, but it's potentially an option.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid trying to inject the caching into Zend_Db directly.

What if you have one query you want to cache for 24 hours, and one you only want to cache for 60 seconds?  How/where do you control that?  Also you would need logic to make sure it only caches SELECT queries, otherwise you are wasting cache space.

I would just use Zend_Cache using the adapter of your choice (libmemcached/apc/xcache for best performance) and handle the caching in your application or data access classes.

You could use a hash of the query itself as the cache key, or depending on the query data, create hash functions for specific queries that are more easily identifiable.  For example, if you had a query that just pulled user account details from the database, the cache key could be something like `userInfoQuery:1234` where 1234 is the user id.

`The query cache does not return stale data. When tables are modified, any relevant entries in the query cache are flushed.`

So if your tables change as a result of insert/update/delete, the query cache is cleared.  If tables change frequently, then the query cache is not very helpful because it is short-lived.

One other common thing you should do in production for Zend_Db is to cache the table meta data.  As you have probably noticed, Zend issues DESCRIBE queries prior to insert(), find(), or info() queries.  Using the table meta cache can eliminate these queries.  See [caching table metadata](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.metadata.caching) for directions on how to do that.

Comment: My approach is essentially the same, except that I push it all down into a repository/service class that is fed a properly configured (lifetime, etc) `Zend_Cache` instance. All those data-access method in the repo/service perform the cache check before undertaking the expensive db operation. And, don't forget, as Drew notes, that when you update any piece of data in the db that would affect the select query result, you probably want to clear all the affected cache entries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @drew010. The metadata caching seems like a pretty painless option to implement right away.

Comment: I'm a big fan of DRY, so I was hoping to minimize the amount `if key in cache return value else execute query, cache result and return` logic. Maybe some refactoring in my mappers and this might become a better option.